# Filter data frame using checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I want to create a scatterplot using R-Shiny App. I need 2 input (selectInput and checkboxGroupInput) to display my plot. When I run the code, it show this error :

> Error: (converted from warning) Error in : (converted from warning)
>   Error in max: (converted from warning) no non-missing arguments to
>   max; returning -Inf

It seems that selectInput is OK but not checkboxGroupInput, because when I try to filter data with 2 selectInput, it works... See my code :

```
ui = fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Title'),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'adv', label = 'Adversaire', choices = levels(nodes$Adversaire)),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'act', label = 'Actions', choices = levels(nodes$Action))
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput('scatter'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data = reactive({
    df = nodes %>%
      filter(Adversaire == input$adv, Action %in% c(input$act)) %>%
      group_by(Player) %>%
      summarise(Poste = unique(Poste),
                Pour_brut = sum(Pour), Contre_brut = sum(Contre), Total_brut = sum(Total),
                Pour = sum(Pour_brut)/mean(unique(Time))*20, Contre = sum(Contre_brut)/mean(unique(Time))*20, Total = sum(Total)/mean(unique(Time))*20,
                Time = mean(unique(Time)))
  })

  output$scatter = renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(), aes(x = Contre, y = Pour, color = Poste, size = Time)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,max(c(data()$Contre, data()$Pour)))) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,max(c(data()$Contre, data()$Pour)))) +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=1) +
      geom_point()
  })      
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT :

```
structure(list(Player = c(14L, 12L, 96L, 25L, 19L, 96L), Poste = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Attaquant", "Defenseur"), class = "factor"), 
    Match = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Adversaire = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Amiens", "Nice"), class = "factor"), 
    Action = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("But", 
    "FO", "JOZO", "PK 4vs5", "PP 5vs3", "PP 5vs4", "SZC", "SZSPR", 
    "TOZD", "TOZN", "TOZO"), class = "factor"), Pour = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Contre = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Total = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Time = c(12.89, 11.33, 
    11.11, 14.42, 10.12, 11.11)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe this is too simple but try not wrapping input$act in c().  It's already a vector.

Comment: I did, but always the same problem..

Comment: Okay so step by step debug, I assume the max() that is the problem is in the scale.  That makes me think that `data()` is empty.   I'm also not sure about your data() function ... what is it returning? shouldn't it return df?

Comment: Yes max() is one problem: but when I neutralize these lines, the code doesn't run.data() isn't a function but a reactive expression using by Shiny, so I have to call like this.

Comment: It'd help if you can share small subset of your data using `dput(head(nodes))`

Comment: I added 'selected' attribute in checkboxGroupInput like this : "checkboxGroupInput(..., selected = levels(nodes$Action)[1])". So it's OK to display the plot, but when I want to check a second level in my checkbox, it return this error: "Error in filter_impl: Evaluation error: (converted from warning) longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length." That makes me think that "filter(Action %in% input$act)" still don't work correctly.

Comment: But it works like a function and if print(data()) you will see that you get nothing. You are creating df  and df is where you need to get the data for your graph.

Comment: You need to put the example data in a form that can be copied and pasted into someone's console. That's why you use dput.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that, so I changed my Edit...

Shree found a solution : after creating df, I call it in the function and it works. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me. Just make sure `Adversaire` and `Action` are character fields. Also added `req(nrow(data()) > 0)` to `renderPlot()` to get rid of `max` function warnings -

```
ui = fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Title'),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'adv', label = 'Adversaire', choices = unique(nodes$Adversaire)),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'act', label = 'Actions', choices = unique(nodes$Action))
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput('scatter'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    df <- nodes %>%
      filter(Adversaire == input$adv, Action %in% input$act) %>%
      group_by(Player) %>%
      summarise(
        Poste = unique(Poste),
        Pour_brut = sum(Pour), Contre_brut = sum(Contre),
        Total_brut = sum(Total),
        Pour = sum(Pour_brut)/mean(unique(Time))*20,
        Contre = sum(Contre_brut)/mean(unique(Time))*20,
        Total = sum(Total)/mean(unique(Time))*20,
        Time = mean(unique(Time))
      )
    df
  })

  output$scatter = renderPlot({
    req(nrow(data()) > 0)
    ggplot(data(), aes(x = Contre, y = Pour, color = Poste, size = Time)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,max(c(data()$Contre, data()$Pour)))) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,max(c(data()$Contre, data()$Pour)))) +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=1) +
      geom_point()
  })      
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]